# How to disable assembly label printing in gdb

Tags: gdb, pretty-print

When I examine memory with `x`, I can see the symbol of the address I am reading:

```
(gdb) x/16zw &pt_table
0x102000 <pt_table>:    0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x102010:    0x00000000 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
```

How can I disable the printing of the label (or move to its own line) so the data is correctly aligned? I cannot find anything on the manual.

Example:

```
(gdb) x/16zw &pt_table
0x102000: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x102010: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
```

Or:

```
(gdb) x/16zw &pt_table
<pt_table>:
0x102000: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x102010: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
```

Comment: Does `pipe x/16zw &pt_table | sed 's/ <.*>//'` work for you? It can be put in a user-defined command to make it easier to type.

Comment: thanks, that solution looses the coloring.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I disable the printing of the label (or move to its own line) so the data is correctly aligned?

I looked at the current GDB source (`print_address_symbolic`) and there *isn't* any way to suppress printing of the `symbol` or `symbol+offset`.

Maybe you want to use LLDB instead.

```
(gdb) list 
1       int abc[100];
2       int main() { return abc[2]; }
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x1129: file t.c, line 2.
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at t.c:2
2       int main() { return abc[2]; }

(gdb) x/8x &abc[1]
0x555555558064 <abc+4>: 0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000
0x555555558074 <abc+20>:        0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000
```

Compare to LLDB:

```
(lldb) run 
Process 3645824 launched: '/tmp/a.out' (x86_64)
Process 3645824 stopped
* thread #1, name = 'a.out', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x0000555555555129 a.out`main at t.c:2:24
   1    int abc[100];
-> 2    int main() { return abc[2]; }

(lldb) x/8x &abc[1]
0x555555558064: 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
0x555555558074: 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
```

Comment: is lldb somehow a "drop in" replacement of gdb, or does it have its own lingo, config, etc (like with vim/emacs)? | **Edit**: this starts to answer my question: [gdb vs lldb](https://aaronbloomfield.github.io/pdr/docs/gdb_vs_lldb.html)

Comment: I use the [dashboard](https://github.com/cyrus-and/gdb-dashboard) .gdbinit UI to have everything I need at glance. Do you know (if you use something like that) a similar thing for LLDB?